# How to count the dates that are not in a list

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe between two dates (date1 date2) with clients and the date of arrive.

```
date1<- "2019-07-29"
date2<- "2019-08-08"

clients<-data.frame(id= c(1:10),
                    arrive=c("2019-07-31", "2019-07-29", "2019-08-01",
                             "2019-08-03", "2019-08-05", "2019-08-08", 
                             "2019-08-02", "2019-08-06", "2019-07-29", 
                             "2019-08-02"),
                    hotel= c(rep(900067, 5), rep(9001649,5)))
```

I want to count between does dates, how many days each hotel did not have a new clients.

Hotel 900067 did not have new clients the following days: 2019-07-30, 2019-08-02, 2019-08-04, 2019-08-06, 2019-08-07, 2019-08-08. This are 6 days between date1 and date2 without any new client.

The dataframe result should be something like:

```
Result<- data.frame(hotel= c(900067, 9001649), 
                    days_without_new_clients= c(6, 7))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a data frame containing all hotel-dates and then see how many that do not exist in the `clients`data.

```
library(dplyr)

all_hotel_dates <- expand.grid(arrive = seq.Date(as.Date("2019-07-29"), as.Date("2019-08-08"), "day"), hotel = c(900067, 9001649))

clients %>%
  mutate(arrive = as.Date(arrive)) %>%
  full_join(all_hotel_dates) %>%
  group_by(hotel) %>%
  summarise(days_without_new_clients = sum(is.na(id)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    hotel days_without_new_clients
    <dbl>                    <int>
1  900067                        6
2 9001649                        7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea via `dplyr` using `complete` to fill in the dates after we filter to the required period, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

clients %>% 
 mutate(arrive = as.Date(arrive)) %>% 
 group_by(hotel) %>% 
 filter(arrive >= as.Date(date1) & arrive <= as.Date(date2)) %>% 
 complete(arrive = seq.Date(as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), 1)) %>%
 summarise(days_no_clients = sum(is.na(id)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#    hotel days_no_clients
#    <dbl>           <int>
#1  900067               6
#2 9001649               7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a udf which receives 2 dates, and returns an array of strings.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
def getDatesBetween(dateA, dateB):
  days = time.difference(dateA, dateB).days
  dates = range(days).map(d => time.add(dateA, d).toString)
  return dates
```

Then create a new column which has the intersection between these dates and the arrival dates.

Comment: It is tagged as `R` question, not python