# How to count the month that you don't have any new client

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe between two dates (date1, date2) with clients and the date of arrive.

```
date1<- "2019-07-29"
date2<- "2019-09-08"

clients<-data.frame(id= c(1:10),
                    arrive=c("2019-07-31", "2019-07-29", "2019-08-01",
                             "2019-08-03", "2019-08-05", "2019-08-08", 
                             "2019-08-02", "2019-08-06", "2019-09-29", 
                             "2019-09-02"),
                    hotel= c(rep(900067, 5), rep(9001649,5)))
```

I want to count between does dates, how many months each hotel did not have a new clients.

Hotel 900067 did not have new clients the following the month 9. And hotel 9001649 did not have a new client the month 7.

The dataframe result should be something like:

```
Result<- data.frame(hotel= c(900067, 9001649), 
                    days_without_new_clients= c(1, 1))
```

I have tried:

```
month_between_dates<-function(date1, date2){
  month1<-month(date1)
  month2<-month(date2)
  if(month1>month2){
    result<-c(month1:12, 1:month2)
  } else {
    result<-c(month1:month2)
  }
  return(result)
}
all_hotel_month <- expand.grid(arrive = month_between_dates(date1, date2), hotel = unique(clients1$hotel))
clients1 %>%
  mutate(arrive = month(as.Date(arrive))) %>%
  group_by(hotel)%>% 
  summarize(month_without_new_clients = sum(is.na(id)))
```

But i get this error:

```
 Error in summarize(., month_without_new_clients = sum(is.na(id))) : argument "by" is missing, with no default*
```

Comment: Didn't you just post this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57753305/5635580)?

Comment: Really similar question but not exacly the same. This time i want to know the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, here is one way. We first create a sequence of dates between `date1` and `date2` and get the `unique` combination of month-year. We extract the month and year from `clients` and get count of months for each `hotel` when they did not have new client.

```
unique_my <- unique(format(seq(as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), "1 day"), "%m-%Y"))

library(dplyr)
clients %>%
   mutate(arrive = as.Date(arrive), 
          month_year = format(arrive, "%m-%Y")) %>%
   group_by(hotel) %>%
   summarise(months_without_new_client = length(setdiff(unique_my, month_year)))

#    hotel months_without_new_client
#    <dbl>                     <int>
#1  900067                         1
#2 9001649                         1
```